# Setting a text view to blank text after being toggled

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, textview

I have a text view that is clickable. Every time the user clicks the text box, it will display a string. When they click it again, the box will become blank. I have this so far:

```
 textToggle.setOnClickListener {
        textToggle.text = "Hello"
    }
```

I have seen some examples where the person did an override on onClick. Would that be the case for here too, or is there a simpler way that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the length of the text when you click on it.

```
textToggle.setOnClickListener {
   if(textToggle.text.length > 0) textToggle.text = ""
   else textToggle.text = "Hello"
}
```

Comment: That isn't working. Clicking it one displays blank text, but clicking again does nothing. I tried swapping the empty string and "Hello" in your code, and it only says Hello when clicked, and doesn't change when clicked again

Comment: It actually worked. Not sure why, but one of my buttons was interfering with it. Thanks!